# Extract JSON using SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to extract the following JSON message using SQL:

```
{
    "document": {
        "Invoice": {
            "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Header: 06IF+230033",
            "InvoiceNumber": "06IF+230033",
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "P0032259",
            "InvoiceLine": [
                {
                    "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Line: 06IF+230033,1",
                    "item": "A05284",
                    "Quantity": "2",
                    "PurchaseOrderLineNumber": "1"
                },
                {
                    "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Line: 06IF+230033,2",
                    "item": "A00019",
                    "Quantity": "10",
                    "PurchaseOrderLineNumber": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to get this data to a table with every InvoiceLine as it's own record.

I tried the following code already:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "document": {
        "Invoice": {
            "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Header: 06IF+230033",
            "InvoiceNumber": "06IF+230033",
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "P0032259",
            "InvoiceLine": [
                {
                    "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Line: 06IF+230033,1",
                    "item": "A05284",
                    "Quantity": "2",
                    "PurchaseOrderLineNumber": "1"
                },
                {
                    "_NavRecordId": "Purch. Inv. Line: 06IF+230033,2",
                    "item": "A00019",
                    "Quantity": "10",
                    "PurchaseOrderLineNumber": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}';

SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice._NavRecordId') AS NavRecordId,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceNumber') AS InvoiceNumber,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.PurchaseOrderNumber') AS PurchaseOrderNumber,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine.item') AS Item,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine.Quantity') AS Quantity,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine.PurchaseOrderLineNumber') AS PurchaseOrderLineNumber
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine') 
    WITH (
        _NavRecordId nvarchar(100) '$._NavRecordId',
        item nvarchar(100),
        Quantity int,
        PurchaseOrderLineNumber int
    ) AS il;
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to fill the item, quantity and the PurchaseOrderLineNumber with the respected data

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output ? also please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice._NavRecordId') AS NavRecordId,
       JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceNumber') AS InvoiceNumber,
       JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.document.Invoice.PurchaseOrderNumber') AS PurchaseOrderNumber,
       il.* -- this includes item, quantity ...
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine') 
    WITH (
        _NavRecordId nvarchar(200) '$._NavRecordId',
        item nvarchar(100),
        Quantity int,
        PurchaseOrderLineNumber int
    ) AS il;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TF8CK-ce)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - SQL Server
Just put the JSON to variable JSON1.
DECLARE @json1 NVarChar(2048)

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(@json1, '$.document.Invoice._NavRecordId') AS NavRecordId,
    JSON_VALUE(@json1, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceNumber') AS InvoiceNumber,
    JSON_VALUE(@json1, '$.document.Invoice.PurchaseOrderNumber') AS PurchaseOrderNumber,
    il._NavRecordId AS [_NavRecordId],
    il.item AS Item,
    il.Quantity,
    il.PurchaseOrderLineNumber
FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.document.Invoice.InvoiceLine') 
WITH (
    _NavRecordId nvarchar(100),
    item nvarchar(100) ,
    Quantity int ,
    PurchaseOrderLineNumber int 
) AS il;
```

Result

[image]